# Insert difference between Table A & Table B into Table B

Tags: mysql, append, difference

Require some assistance here.

**Situation:**
I have 2 identical table. Table A and Table B. Table A is a live DB and Table B is a copy of the live DB. I would like to append the difference/new data from Table A into Table B. How could I go about doing so?

I have first and foremost computed the difference, but am unable to figure out a way to insert the difference into Table B. Please advise. Thanks in advance. Much obliged.

```
select OrderID, CustomerKey, Orderdate
from (select OrderID, CustomerKey, Orderdate from Table A
union all
select OrderID, CustomerKey, Orderdate from TableB) tbl
group by OrderID, CustomerKey, Orderdate
having count(*) = 1
order by OrderID;
```

from here how do i append the difference into Table B? Any ideas?

Best Regards,
D

Comment: Do you want get records those exist in tableA but does not exist in tableB and then you want to insert these records in table B...

Comment: Yes @ZafarMalik, your right. That's the desired outcome.

Comment: order id is seems primary key in both tables. is it correct.